# error in javascript conditional statement

Tags: javascript, if-statement, return, conditional-statements

I am facing an issue in javascript. if `key` value is true they stop it return `true` whereas if `key` value is `false` they shows `Error`.

Problem: they don't read the condition `number` or `name` value in `if body`. if key value is `true` they terminate.

How should i handle this condition? that they should also read the condition `number` or `name` value in `if body`.

can i use else if statement here ?

```js
 var key = $('#key').val().trim();
            
 if(key != "" ){
    return true;     //value is true  if value is true they stopped it
 }

 if(key === ''){
    showError();   //this field is required
    return false;
 }

//if key value is true they don't execute my number or name condition 

if ( $('#number').val().trim() === '' || $('#name').val().trim() === '' )
   {
    if ($('#number').val().trim() === '') { 
    showError();   //this field is required
    }
   if ($('#name').val().trim() === '') {
    showError();   //this field is required
   }
     return false;
   }
   else{
     return true;           //always return true
   }
```

how can i do? anyone help me?

Comment: Your script exits execution with a value of either `true` or `false`, depending on `value`'s value so it never makes it to the `if` (exits on lines `4` or `9`). Please read what [return](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/return) does. Basically you want to remove the `return true` part (line `4`). It terminates the script returning `true`. You probably want it to continue execution and get to the `if` part.

Comment: is this code part of a function?

Comment: yes but the problem if user type `key, number or name` value in input field they return the true. [@](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1891677/tao)

Comment: yes it part of function [@](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2067047/amars)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you wanted. Have a look. The code continues after checking key.

```js
var key = $('#key').val().trim();

 if(key === ''){
    showError();   //this field is required
    let keyStat = false;
 }

//if key value is true they don't execute my number or name condition 

if ( $('#number').val().trim() === '' || $('#name').val().trim() === '' || keyStat === false) {
    if ($('#number').val().trim() === '') { 
      showError();   //this field is required
    }
    if ($('#name').val().trim() === '') {
      showError();   //this field is required
    }
    if (!keyStat) {
      showError();   //this field is required
    }
      return false;
    }
 else{
   return true;           //always return true
 }
```

Comment: thanks i try your logic [@](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2067047/amars)

Comment: i ask one thing if  `keyStat = true  or undefined ` what should i do? [@](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2067047/amars)

Answer (score 0):

when you call return statement your function will **exit**,only code before the return statement will run

Example:

```js
function bar(){
var key = 12

if(key === 12){
  console.log("only code before the return statement will run")
  return true; // when you call return your function will exit
}

console.log("this will be terminated")
}
```

```html
<a href="#" onclick="bar()"> click me </a>
```

Comment: thanks your response. [@](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13665108/mohammed-khaled)